# ASP.NET session state after closing browser

Tags: asp.net, session

I use VS2010 and C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, my users can login with their own username/pass and then they can view site. I want to limit users so that each users cannot login simultaneously with one username, i.e. when a user has logged in with his username, he this username cannot be logged-in again until they have logged out.

I create a session for each user when he logins (session["userid"]= user_id_obtained_from_database), I'm going to check all active sessions when when a user logins. I'll only allow my user to login if there is no active session["userid"] with his userid.

I remove all user sessions when he logouts, but what happens when a user suddenly closes his browser page? in this case how can I destroy user session id so that he can login again? will user session remain open until the session expires? so if a user closes browser page (instead of logging out), he cannot login again until his sessions expires on server?

Answer (score 3):

You can fire an AJAX call on the body `onbeforeunload` event to register the exit of a page.  If you get one of these with no further page request then the user has left your site.

Comment: thanks friend, where should I put this event? on each page or on global.asax? is there any sample describing it more?

Comment: You need to put the code to call the AJAX in the HTML : `<body onbeforeunload="ajaxFunctionLeavePage()">`.  You should have the AJAX call an `ashx` handler that deals with the session info passed through.